# Background fails to load on click in firefox and IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, background

I am working on a style changer/switcher that changes background patterns of the theme "body".
I succeeded in implementing into my template, but here comes the sad part.

I have changed the property to css attribute in the jQuery as "background-image" which worked well with all browsers.
here : http://jsfiddle.net/envira/xs73J/9/

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.backgrounds li').click(function(){
    $colbgSrc = $(this).css('background-image');
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'bgnone')
        $colbgSrc = "none";
    $('body').css('background-image',$colbgSrc);
    $.cookie('background', $colbgSrc);
    $.cookie('backgroundclass', $(this).attr('class').replace('active',''));
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});     
 $(function(){
    $colbgSrc = $.cookie('background');
    $('body').css('background-image',$colbgSrc);
    $('.backgrounds').find('li.' + $.cookie('backgroundclass')).addClass('active');
        });
    });
```

But when i changed the CSS attribute class in jQuery code to "background", there is error in Firefox and IE as the backgrounds are not clickable.
this one : http://jsfiddle.net/xs73J/5/

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.backgrounds li').click(function(){
    $colbgSrc = $(this).css('background');
    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'bgnone')
        $colbgSrc = "none";
    $('body').css('background',$colbgSrc);
    $.cookie('background', $colbgSrc);
    $.cookie('backgroundclass', $(this).attr('class').replace('active',''));
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});     
 $(function(){
    $colbgSrc = $.cookie('background');
    $('body').css('background',$colbgSrc);
    $('.backgrounds').find('li.' + $.cookie('backgroundclass')).addClass('active');
});
    });
```

I tried editing the css values but none proved successful.
so i wish i could find some one here who could fix my issue.

The sole reason for this being i want the patterns to repeat and the larger images not to repeat when clicked.

Help is appreciated,
Thank you
regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `background` with the jQuery function `.ccs()` appears to be a bug in Firefox (see [LINK](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/firefox-bug-or-jquery-bug-in-css)), I suggest you to stick with `background-image`.

As you have mentioned that you intent to repeat the patterns images but not for the larger images, I suggest you to use the following approach, which I have tested in both Firefox and IE (and Chrome):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xs73J/10/)

#### HTML

Change the class of the `div` element that wraps the list of the larger images from `patterns` to `images`

#### JS

Add additonal logic to determine whether the clicked image is a pattern or cover image in the `.click` event:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.backgrounds li').click(function(){
        $colbgSrc = $(this).css('background-image');
        if ($(this).attr('class') == 'bgnone')
            $colbgSrc = "none";
        $('body').css('background-image',$colbgSrc);
        /* Additional logic starts here */
        if ($(this).parents("div.images").length) {
            $('body').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');
            $('body').css('background-size', '100%');
        } else {
            $('body').css('background-repeat','repeat');   
            $('body').css('background-size', '');
        }
        /* Additional logic ends here */
        $.cookie('background', $colbgSrc);
        $.cookie('backgroundclass', $(this).attr('class').replace('active',''));
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });     
     $(function(){
        $colbgSrc = $.cookie('background');
        $('body').css('background-image',$colbgSrc);
        $('.backgrounds').find('li.' + $.cookie('backgroundclass')).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello buddy @chiwangc i have a minor issue, upon page refresh with large backgrounds, the extra css properties are not being recognized , like the background-attachment, position etc. The images are repeating, is there any fix for that. regards

Comment: @EnviraPhani You can store the `background-repeat` value in the cookie using `$.cookie()` (like what you did for the `background-image`) and then restore the corresponding value when the page is loaded. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xs73J/13/)

Comment: That really works bro !!! Thanks again for the fix, hmm i just ignored the cookie lol. Thanks it works like a charm. Perfect. @chiwangc regards